# Screenshot for the entire page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to take a screenshot for the entire page and download it using javaScript or html? Not only for a specific canvas (I want the entire thing).

Comment: Did you do your research?

Comment: @AdamAzad Yes I did and the only thing i saw is canvas2html or drawImage() function which both are not helpful for me. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @AdamAzad adding to that the form button which also required a tag id to work

Comment: In what form are they *not helpful*?

Comment: @AdamAzad canvas2html will screenshot a canvas for you. In my case I have a streaming video from the webcam so that canvas will not capture it.

Comment: The library is html2canvas https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: I know this library. I worked with it for a long time. It will not capture a streaming video. That is why I need to catch the entire page. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Web pages are not the best things to be "screenshoted", because of their nature; they can include async elements

You should try https://www.url2png.com
But is not a good idea.